# how to get data returned by mysql_fetch_object() in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

how to get data returned by mysql_fetch_object() in a variable. i am using below mentioned code....
i am trying to fetch dates from DB based on condition and also want that the value to be stored in variable one by one . But when this code executes it print all the values returned by stdobj.

```
<?php
    $connect=mysql_connect('host','user','xyz') ;
    echo mysql_error();
    $db=mysql_select_db("file_date",$connect);
    echo  mysql_error();
    $append_d="00:00:00";
    $date_test=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-20 days"));
    $full_d="$date_test "."$append_d";
    $query_d=mysql_query("SELECT time as time_f FROM table WHERE date>='$full_d'");
    $data_s = "";
    while ($row_s = mysql_fetch_object($query_d)) {
      $x_gmail=$row_s->time_f;
      echo $x_gmail;
    }
?>
```

below is the sample output

> -:2013-09-08 13:45:292013-09-09 14:19:192013-09-10 17:30:072013-09-12 11:39:492013-09-12 12:09:492013-09-12 14:09:482013-09-12 16:09:472013-09-12 18:04:472013-09-12 19:09:462013-09-13 00:05:442013-09-13 17:09:372013-09-14 00:04:342013-09-15 22:59:542013-09-16 12:05:492013-09-16 13:10:482013-09-16 15:35:472013-09-16 19:05:462013-09-17 13:44:382013-09-18 00:05:342013-09-18 12:05:292013-09-18 14:34:272013-09-18 16:45:272013-09-18 17:35:272013-09-19 13:45:182013-09-19 21:05:152013-09-20 13:46:082013-09-23 12:59:392013-09-23 13:45:372013-09-24 13:45:272013-09-25 00:10:23

i want that for 1st value 2013-09-08 13:45:29 can be assigned to any variable so when i echo variable x it will print 2013-09-08 13:45:29 not the whole object string.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you only want one row, put `LIMIT 1` in the query.

Comment: You're not printing the whole object string. You're printing each individual value one at a time. It's the fact that you're doing it in a loop, with no linebreaks or spacing capability that it looks like a blob of text.

Comment: Just store it in a variable rather than echoing it out.

Comment: that is what i am unable to do ....i want to print only 1st row value when function mysql_fetch_object() returns it in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're now printing each date string inside the `while` loop. That's not the whole object string -- they're individual strings, but it just appears as a big chunk since you're not using linebreaks to separate them.

If you want only one date string, then you can use `LIMIT` clause in your SQL query:

```
SELECT time as time_f FROM table WHERE date>='$full_d' LIMIT 1;
```

But however, if you want to have all the date string, but want to echo only the first one, then you could store them in an array and re-use it later:

```
while ($row_s = mysql_fetch_object($query_d)) {
    $x_gmail[] = $row_s->time_f;
}
```

And you can use it like so:

```
$x = $x_gmail[0];
echo $x;
```

That'll just print the first item.

Comment: i had just tried as you suggested but it result same. i had used $x = $x_gmail[0];
echo $x; but whole string get printed as mentioned above.

Comment: when LIMIT 1 is used than it can be done but i need to use every returned so that i may save them some variable in one go  and use.

Comment: @abhinavdixit: You need to print it **outside** the loop. Read the answer again.